# Skipping outline table of contents of some sections in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents

I'm trying to make a table of contents for a beamer presentation, and I want to have the outline show up for every section except the first. Right now I'm using:

```
\AtBeginSection[] {
  \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Overview}
      \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
}
```

Normally I can do this using `\section*`, but that makes it not show up in the table of contents at all. Is there a way to have it do the table of contents after every section, but skip the first one and still have the first section in the table of contents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a conditional based on the `section` counter to decide whether to include the table of contents frame. Here, I use the `\ifnumcomp` macro from `etoolbox`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginSection[] {
\ifnumcomp{\value{section}}{=}{1}{}
  {
  \begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Overview}
      \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame}
  }
}
```

If the section number is 1, then the first (empty) set of braces will be used. Otherwise the second set of braces (with the frame in it) will be used.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: How about multiple sections to block? e.g.: section 2 and section 3? Or section 1 and section 3?

Comment: @math: `\ifinlist` from `etoolbox` can handle that.